# Use reduce to shorten array

Tags: javascript

Use reduce to find number of times an items is in an array.
The array could have arrays inside recursively.

```
var foo = [
  1,
  [2, 3, 4], 
  4, [5,6,7], 4
];
```

`bar(foo, 4)` would return 3.

Comment: In your example, why would `bar(foo, "a")` return `3`, although `"a"` occurs only twice in its input?

Comment: @NorCallKnockOut Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: foo is not an object, it's an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var foo = [1, [2, 3, 4], 4, [5, 6, 7], 4];

function f(arr, item) {
  return arr.reduce(function (s, i) {
    if (Array.isArray(i)) return s+f(i, item);
    return s+(i==item?1:0);
  }, 0);
}

console.log(f(foo, 4))
```

The function `f` is a recursive function. We loop over all the items and reduce them to one number. The function would be called on all the inner arrays as well, and for the non-array items, we just check them to be equal to the desired item.

Comment: What is the second parameter of the first return doing?  the , 0);

Comment: Ahh. Awesome.  This is really clean.  Thank you

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut at first, `s` would be initialized to init value (0), then it is going to call the function on all element and store the return value to `s` again and call the function on the next element. That's how `reduce` works.

Comment: The second param of reduce is not 0 by default. If not passed, the accumulator is initialized with the first element of the array and the function is called for all the other elements. Example: `a=["One","Two","Tree"]` compare `a.reduce((t,v)=>t+v.length)` and `a.reduce((t,v)=>t+v.length,0)` (using compact form of function call)

Answer (score 4):

You can count all items with one call with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

And a check if the element is an array, then the function is called again with the array as parameter.

```js
var foo = ["a", ["b", "c", "d"], "a"],
    object = {};

function count(a, o) {
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        if (Array.isArray(b)) {
            count(b, o);
        } else {
            o[b] = (o[b] || 0) + 1;
        }
    })
}

count(foo, object);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: OP is asking for a recursive function.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto This calls `count` from within `count`; isn't that the definition of recursive?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just didn't see that. `:)`

Comment: @NinaScholz Much better :)

Answer (score 2):

So if you want a recursion (And it'll work in any browser):

```
var foo = [
    "a",
    ["b", "c", "d"], 
    "a"
];

function bar(arr, item) {
    var count = 0;
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        var v = arr[i];
        if (typeof v === "string") {
            if (v === item) {
                count++;
            }
        } else {
            count = count + bar(v, item);
        }
    }

    return count;
}

console.log(bar(foo, "a"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another functional type of interpretation that doesn't require an external state, although would be more inefficient.

```js
var foo = [
  "a",
  ["b", "c", "d"],
  ["a", "b"],
  "a"
];

function flatten( arr ){
  return arr.reduce(function( ret, curr ){
    return ret.concat( Array.isArray( curr ) ? flatten( curr ) : [ curr ] );
  }, []);
}

function filterBy( arr, val ){
  return arr.filter(function( item ){
    return item === val;
  })
}

console.log( flatten( foo ) );
console.log( filterBy( flatten( foo ), 'a') );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) you can count number of occurrence of each element with this code:

```
_.countBy(_.flatten(array), _.identity)
```

So function foo can be implemented like this:

```
function bar(foo, element){
    return _.countBy(_.flatten(foo), _.identity)[element];
}
var foo = ["a", ["b", "c", "d"], "a"]
console.log(bar(foo, "a"));
```

Although this solution isn't recursive I find it worth mentioning.